# Reactivity of meta and para xylene towards nitration

Tags: organic-chemistry

Is meta xylene more reactive towards nitration or is it para xylene?

I would say it is meta xylene as it has two methyl groups meta to each other. Since both are activating groups, there would be a greater electron density at the ortho and para positions with respect to both the groups. This would make meta xylene more susceptible to nitration (EAS) as compared to para xylene.

Comment: Yes, [see here](https://books.google.com/books?id=QA49AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA188&lpg=PA188&dq=xylene,+relative+rates+of+nitration&source=bl&ots=qZlszXf727&sig=Ccs-eRHUIjshr8toIyx71XdRtRo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjxppyF-L_RAhXow1QKHVu3Bxg4ChDoAQg_MAg#v=onepage&q=xylene%2C%20relative%20rates%20of%20nitration&f=false), p. 188.